# Inner Query in place of AND NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Im trying to run a complex code with around 10 AND NOT EXISTS condition. Can I replace with INNER Join?

```
-----Initial Query---------

Select a FROM A1 WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (select 1 from B1 WHERE A1.a = B1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from C1 WHERE A1.a = C1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from D1 WHERE A1.a = D1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from E1 WHERE A1.a = E1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from F1 WHERE A1.a = F1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from G1 WHERE A1.a = G1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from H1 WHERE A1.a = H1.a)
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from I1 WHERE A1.a = I1.a)

----Processed Query-------

SELECT a FROM A1 WHERE a NOT IN (
Select a FROM A1 a1 WHERE 
INNER JOIN B1 b1 WHERE a1.a = b1.a)
INNER JOIN C1 c1 WHERE a1.a = c1.a)
INNER JOIN D1 d1 WHERE a1.a = d1.a)
INNER JOIN E1 e1 WHERE a1.a = e1.a)
INNER JOIN F1 f1 WHERE a1.a = f1.a)
INNER JOIN G1 g1 WHERE a1.a = g1.a)
INNER JOIN H1 h1 WHERE a1.a = h1.a)
INNER JOIN I1 i1 WHERE a1.a = i1.a))
```

Thanks..

Comment: Perhaps the bigger issue is about your schema. Poorly designed schemas will require awkward and inefficient code.

Comment: @SMor It was just an example on how my real query is...I just used different column names for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negating an `inner join` is not what you want.

You could write that as a `left join` and then filter out `NULLs` in the where clause.

By writing it the way you have, you are forcing SQL Server to read and join all those tables in memory, possibly spilling to disk, in order to build a worktable.

Once compiled to an execution plan, a left join will likely result in the same left anti-semi join operation. However if your requirement is to logically exclude rows, `not exists` is the preferable and more performant way.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @sTTu, that syntax does not work.

There is another syntax that works, though:

```sql
SELECT a, whatever_other_columns_here
FROM A1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(

SELECT A1.a    -- note no FROM here
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM B1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM C1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM D1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM E1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM F1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM G1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM H1
INTERSECT
SELECT a FROM I1
)
```

You can do the same thing by switching `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS` and `INTERSECT` to `EXCEPT`